# Completely general purpose code on a GPU

Tags: c, programming-languages, opencl, gpgpu, computation-theory

I was approached by a client to work on a project that will involve trying to run full scale programs on the GPU with OpenCL.

I have decent knowledge of CUDA and low level machine architecture. As far as I understand, GPU code does not have a call stack, nor does it have pointers, or any unstructured control flow mechanism like goto, exceptions or function pointers. 
To me it resembles a rudimentary FORTRAN dialect in terms of semantics.
I know that GPU kernels called from another GPU kernel get inlined like macro expansions, there is no CALL/RET mechanism

As far as I understand, you cannot have a lexically scoped language without a stack and the dialect that OpenCL compiles is a very flat subset of C and similarly CUDA, while allowing templates and stuff, gives us only a very small subset of C++

The client wants to translate from Javascript to C to LLVM and then to OpenCL bytecode, or somehow get full scale programs to run on the GPU, even if they run slowly with no parallelism

Am I right in convincing the client that what he hopes to achieve is technically impossible and not really useful?

Comment: The first part *'technical impossible'* seems a bit strong, I assume it could be possible using (lots of) clever tricks, if one really wants to spend/waste his time on this. The second part *'not really useful'* is probably correct, using a general purpose CPU seems much more sensible to execute a general purpose language like JavaScript or C... But these are just my thoughts nothing definitive!

Comment: Can you implement a full language like C on an architecture without a call stack, pointers and goto?

Can one do without CALL/RET especially? Can every function call be completely inlined regardless of code size and efficiency? Are there any recursive algorithms that cannot be done by iteration?

Comment: One cannot do so directly, but after giving it some thought it might be possible using the 'clever tricks'. I have seen lots of creative minds/code to dismiss the possibility entirely. But as I mentioned: It might be a waste of time (and thus certainly not interesting for your client)!

Comment: I am fairly confident that OpenCL is Turing-equivalent; so yes, any program (logic) that can be performed with C on a CPU can be simulated with OpenCL on a GPU (or, take a weaker version: every problem that can be solved using C on a CPU can be solved using OpenCL on a GPU) - ignoring issues of I/O, etc. However, it makes absolutely no sense to put entire programs on GPUs. The whole point of using GPUs is to accelerate certain kinds of computations; performance of most computations would suffer. Roasting chicken makes it better for eating; roasting Jello wouldn't have the same effect.

Comment: There have been several similar projects to produce integrated progamming models that run across CPU and GPU code. For example NumbaPro and Copperhead both allow Python code to compile down to  the GPU. So this is possible but not trivial by any means. C++ AMP also allows the developer to write inline C++ code that compiles to the GPU. You would only be able to implement a subset of the language. As noted by rep_movsd GPUs do not support a full set of features.